# Where should you put dart source code in an existing server-side web project?

Tags: dart

If I'm just getting started authoring and managing my client source code using dart within a PHP or Rails project (similar to haxe or coffeescript), what convention(s) should be used for project structure?

Does any of this change if I say I'm mainly going to be transpiling my code to JavaScrpt?

Answer (score 1):

Dart package layout conventions:

```
http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html
```

The more relevant parts for a client side dart application:

```
http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html#public-libraries
http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html#implementation-files
http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html#web-files
```

Long story short, put your dart libraries in the `lib/` folder. The Dart scripts in here define what other packages (including your `web/`) can import and use. Entry points--scripts with main()--cannot go in the lib folder.

Files in `lib/` can me imported with `import "package:project_name/file_name.dart"`.

Internal libraries that should only be imported and used inside of the package should be put in `lib/src/`.

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the question to be a bit more specific.

Comment: You've got me on that one then. I'm using Dart in a couple of projects where it is the entire client side. It hooks up to REST webservices and using apache with proxy pass to debug in dartium. You could do something similar, i.e. have a proxy pass url that goes to your dartium debugger for all dart scripts. You'd probably want some build automation for deploy that switches it over to run with compiled javascript and copies the dart out/ to your project. I'm not saying this is how you should do it, I just don't know a better way to do it.

Comment: That's sort of what I've got going now.  I've made a grunt dart task and it watches for changes to code and packages it all up.